# How do I save chromepass data via batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I tried to save the data from `chromepass` with `/stext` command, which should work according to their site.

Code:

```
Start chromepass.exe /stext chromepass.txt
```

Comment: [so] is a programmers site, your question sems a bit off topic here. If your original command contains any double quotes start uses this argument as the window title - insert a dummy pair of double qoutes immediatly following start then.

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having when you try to do this? How can we help?

Answer (score 1):

You might be using the version that has no support for command line.

> Command-line options removed from the official release of my password-recovery tools, it's constantly detected by many Antivirus programs as malware/Trojan/Virus or as a security risk.

According to his [blog](http://blog.nirsoft.net/2014/09/22/command-line-options-removed-from-the-official-release-of-my-password-recovery-tools/)

You can find a version with command line supported [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/password_recovery_tools.html).

**Hope this was helpful to you :)**